# How can I fake existential types in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle, existential-type

Consider the following Isabelle/HOL definition of a simple process language:

```
typedecl channel

datatype process = Put channel char process | Get "char ⇒ process" | Stop
```

This languages supports sending and receiving of characters via channels.

Now I’d like to have typed channels. The `channel` type should have the type of values it can transport as a parameter:

```
typedecl 'a channel
```

The `Put` and `Get` data constructors should have the following (polymorphic) types:

```
Put :: "['a channel, 'a, process] ⇒ process"
Get :: "['a channel, 'a ⇒ process] ⇒ process"
```

However, this requires support for existential quantification in data types, which Isabelle/HOL doesn’t have.

I tried to fake existential quantification and came up with the following attempt:

```
typedecl put
axiomatization put :: "['a channel, 'a] ⇒ put" where
  put_inject: "put a x = put b y ⟷ a = b ∧ x = y"

bnf_axiomatization 'r get
axiomatization get :: "['a channel, 'a ⇒ 'r] ⇒ 'r get" where
  get_inject: "get a f = get b g ⟷ a = b ∧ f = g"

datatype process = Put put process | Get "process get" | Stop
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error message:

```
Type definition with open dependencies, use "typedef (overloaded)" or enable configuration option "typedef_overloaded" in the context.
  Type:  process
  Deps:
  map_get(process.process_IITN_process
          ⇒ (process_pre_process_bdT + process_pre_process_bdT process_pre_process) set ⇒ bool,
           (process_pre_process_bdT + process_pre_process_bdT process_pre_process) set ⇒ bool),
  bd_get,
  set_get(process.process_IITN_process
          ⇒ (process_pre_process_bdT + process_pre_process_bdT process_pre_process) set ⇒ bool)
The error(s) above occurred in typedef "process"
```

Is my attempt reasonable, and, if yes, how can I solve this problem? Is there a better solution?

Comment: I discovered meanwhile that the existence of that injective function `get` makes the `get` type a *non-bounded* functor which contradicts the statement that it is a *bounded* natural functor (BNF). Thus this code should introduce logical inconsistency. However, that should be fixable by bounding the cardinality of `'a`, for example by requiring that `'a` is an instance of `countable`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the axiom for `get` is inconsistent with the `bnf_axiomatization`. However, if you restrict yourself to countable types `'a`, then such a type exists. As soon as you fix such a cardinality bound, you do not even have to restort to axiomatization. Existential types can then be emulated within HOL using encoding and decoding functions into/from a universal domain.

For example, for countable types, the natural numbers can be used as the universal domain. This has been used, e.g., in `Imperative_HOL` to model a heap that can store typed values, see [the paper from 2008](http://www21.in.tum.de/~krauss/imperative/). Huffman has done something similar for [HOLCF](http://www21.in.tum.de/~huffman/papers/tphols2009.pdf), Isabelle's domain theory library.

With such an encoding in place, you'd construct the datatype of processes using untyped channels and then create a type-safe view on the datatype using the encoding and decoding functions as necessary.